# Where can I download GCC binaries for windows?

Tags: windows, gcc, download

I want to play around with GCC 4.5 but on [GCC's](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/binaries.html) site it says that they don't supply binaries. I think downloading the source and building GCC from scratch is a bit of overkill (even if the OS I'm using (Windows) is rather obscure).

Where can I download GCC 4.5 for Windows?

(I don't want all of Cygwin, just GCC)

Comment: "...even if the OS, I'm using, Windows, is rather obscure". That deserves about a thousand upvotes. Here's one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try tdm-gcc for windows http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download

Answer (score 5):

Does [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) work for you?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want cygwin, try [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/) instead, it's smaller. There is no gcc.exe.

Comment: I tried MinGW and got version 3.4.5 of GCC for some reason

Comment: Try http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/ there's a gcc-core-4.5-...

Answer (score 3):

Download gcc free binary builds for different architectures here http://www.comsytec.com/products/gnu-binaries/gcc-binaries.html

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend the binaries from [MinGW-builds](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/), they are just so full of win:

- Prompt builds of the latest GCC versions.
- Binaries for both 32 and 64-bit hosts are available.
- Both kinds of binaries can target 32 and 64-bit platforms (to produce 32-bit compiles from the 64-bit binaries use `-m32`; for the converse, `-m64`).
- Both kinds of binaries are available with your choice of POSIX or win32 threading models.
- You also get to choose between [exception handling implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670169/what-is-difference-between-sjlj-vs-dwarf-vs-seh): DW2 or SJLJ for 32-bit binaries and SEH or SJLJ for 64-bit binaries.

For more information on the above and an evaluation of lots of prebuilt binary sources, check [this page](http://qt-project.org/wiki/MinGW-64-bit) from the Qt wiki so that you can judge on your own. If you do decide on MinGW-builds, start browsing for your binaries [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/releases/).

Answer (score 2):

http://gcc.gnu.org/install/binaries.html

Through MinGW or Cygwin, as GNU does not provide binaries.

Answer (score 1):

Try here [www.comsytec.com](http://www.comsytec.com) for cross compilers and debuggers